# Width of image = headwidth when head is textwithmarginpar

Tags: header-footer, margins, koma-script

Using `scrbook` and `scrpage2` with a headwith of `textwithmarginpar`, I am trying to set individual images in the textbody to this wider headwidth. `\hoffset` is `0pt`. Adding up `\textwidth`, `\marginparwidth` and `\marginparsep` gives me more than the headwidth, however: image and pagenumber do not end on the same line. There appears to be another length affecting the headwidth. Thankful for any idea!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc,BCOR=15mm}   

\newlength{\TextwithMargin}
\setlength{\TextwithMargin}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\TextwithMargin}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\TextwithMargin}{\marginparsep}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\lehead[]{{\pagemark}\quad\rightmark}
\rohead[]{{\rightmark}\quad\pagemark}
\setheadwidth[]{textwithmarginpar} % As expected, I get the same result when using \TextwithMargin.


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{scrheadings}
\addsec{Section}
\begin{figure}[hptp]
\checkoddpage
\edef\side{\ifoddpage l\else r\fi}%
\makebox[\textwidth][\side]{%
\parbox{\TextwithMargin}{%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Example image.}
}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can compile your document, but I can't tell what the result is that you were hoping to, alternately, achieve.

Comment: The page number and the image should end on the same line. Is that clearer?

Comment: `scrpage2` is obsolete, try `scrlayer-scrpage` instead.

Comment: Of course. I should have included: Using scrpage2 because my tex distribution comes via the Ubuntu repositories. It is therefore a bit older than the current version. In order to use scrlayer-scrpage, I'd have to reinstall my whole tex distribution manually. Not particularly called for in the middle of a project, unless absolutely necessary...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will use a `headsepline` to show the width of the headlines.

With `scrlayer-scrpage` the option `headwidth=textwithmarginpar` works as expected:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
%\providecommand*\Ifthispageodd{\ifthispageodd}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm]{geometry}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc,BCOR=15mm}

\newlength{\TextwithMargin}
\setlength{\TextwithMargin}{%
  \dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}

\usepackage[headwidth=textwithmarginpar,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{{\pagemark}\quad\rightmark}
\rohead{{\rightmark}\quad\pagemark}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\addsec{Section}
\blindtext[4]
\begin{figure}[htb]
\Ifthispageodd{\edef\side{l}}{\edef\side{r}}%
\makebox[\textwidth][\side]{%
\parbox{\TextwithMargin}{%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Example image.}
}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, using `scrlayer-scrpage` with option `headwidth=textwithmarginpar` the headline is not centered above the textarea.

Additionally the KOMA-Script classes define a command `\Ifthispageodd`.

---

Here is also a suggestion with the obsolete package `scrpage2`

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
%\providecommand*\Ifthispageodd{\ifthispageodd}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm]{geometry}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc,BCOR=15mm}

\newlength{\TextwithMargin}
\setlength{\TextwithMargin}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\lehead{{\pagemark}\quad\rightmark}
\rohead{{\rightmark}\quad\pagemark}
\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\addsec{Section}
\blindtext[4]
\begin{figure}[htb]
\Ifthispageodd{\edef\side{l}}{\edef\side{r}}%
\makebox[\textwidth][\side]{%
\parbox{\TextwithMargin}{%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Example image.}
}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Note you have to use the optional argument:

```
\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar}
```

If the optional offset `0pt` is missing the headline will bei centered above the text area.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! That solved the never-ending search for that unknown length. I am a bit surprised that leaving out the '\hoffset' results in a different output,, however. The documentation for KOMA emphasizes, after all, that it would be '0pt' by default when '\setheadwidth{textwithmarginpar}'. Many thanks for explaining and visualizing ;).